# Change URL address for hosted website in IIS

Tags: iis

I've hosted my project in IIS, so That it's available at the following URL:

> /myMachineName:3557/

How to change that URL to be `/TestWebsite` and without the port number?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this several ways, including web.config. The simplest way is to use the IIS management UI. [See here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc770409%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for instructions.

Comment: Redirecting has nothing to do with the OP question. He just wants to make his website available at the different URL.